# C++ Need Solution for converting from const string

Tags: c++, string

I have a (little) Problem. I was going to program a little string class in C++, which should allow you to use a string in the same way as a string in C#.

I wrote the following class:

```
class STRING
{
private:
  char * data;
  int length;

public:
  STRING();
  STRING(char * data);
  //string(char[] data, int length);

  void setData(char * data);

  int Length();
  char * toString();


  STRING operator = (STRING data);
  STRING operator = (char * data);
  STRING operator = (char data);
  STRING operator = (const string data);
  STRING operator + (STRING data);
  friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&os, const STRING& data);


  void display();


};
```

It is working. But I have one problem. If I try to initiate a new object of my class and want to set it with a value like:

```
STRING test1;
test1 = "TEST";
```

The compiler give me the following warning:
warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ 
[-Wwrite-strings] test1 = "TEST";

So I try to get a solution in form of an operation overloading. I tried this:

```
  STRING STRING::operator = (const string data)
  {
     char * tmp;
     int laenge;
     tmp = (char *) data
     laenge = strlen(tmp);
     this->data = new char[laenge + 1];
     this->length = laenge;

     strcpy(this->data, tmp);
  }
```

But it dont work and I'm out of ideas. Of cause it would work if I initiate it with:

```
STRING test1;
test1 = (char *) "TEST";
```

but my Dream is to use it like: STRING test1; test1 = "TEST"; or 
STRING test1 = "TEST";

Comment: This is broken in too many ways to address in one post. Better learn some more C++ first.

Comment: I don't think you can cast the c++ string datatype as a pointer to char array, i.e. "tmp = (char *) data" won't work. Have a look at http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need an overload that takes a `const char*`

```
STRING STRING::operator = (const char* s)
{
    if (data != nullptr)
        delete [] data;
    length = strlen(s);
    data = new char[length + 1];

    strcpy(data, s);
}
```

Comment: please bare in mind that this solution is prone to memory leaks.

Comment: @Pandrei I fixed the memory leak issue.

Comment: `STRING s; s = nullptr;` will crash your implementation in the `strlen` call.

Comment: @utnapistim: It may not. But it'll be UB regardless.

Comment: @utnapistim You can always "= delete" an overload taking an std::nullptr_t. The caller can still pass a null char*, but at that point the caller is responsible for the Undefined Behavior

Answer (score 1):

You Need an overloaded function for `const char*` but you can also use a template function which will be faster:

```
template<int length>
STRING STRING::operator = (const char (&s)[length])
{
    //resize or allocate data if needed
    strncpy(data, s, length);
}
```

Comment: Faster and far less flexible.

Comment: Should be `const char (&s)[length]`. Otherwise it will be taking an array of references.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the argument types from `char*` to `char const*` in the following functions.

```
STRING(char * data);
STRING operator = (char * data);
```

Also, as a matter of general improvement, you can change

```
STRING operator = (STRING data);
STRING operator = (const string data);
STRING operator + (STRING data);
```

to

```
STRING& operator = (STRING const& data);
STRING& operator = (const string& data);
STRING operator + (STRING const& data) const;
```

See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators why my suggested prototypes are more appropriate than what you have.